# Call secured application method outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, httpd.conf

I have a rails application with apache, passenger, with kerberos protection.

One of the controllers (UsersController) provides one action (responds with json) that must be available externally.

When i try to access it ($ curl ...), the server returns Kerberos authentication error.

What should i do in this kind of situations. Configure httpd.conf to 'allow any' for one specific file, isolating the externally available methods in one file or is it a better solution?

Comment: please specify more what your configuration is

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it configuring the specific dir in apache httpd.conf

```
<Location "/users/user_action.json*">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    satisfy any
</Location>
```

Thanks